# A way to "improve" write coding in vs2008 experience

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to try to automize some recurrent job when i develop asp.net application.

For example, for each `<asp:button>` I create, I would like to insert the classical code

```
onomouseover="...something"  
onmouseout=" ..something-again.."
```

Is there a way to automatically add this code "piece" in vs 2008? 
Some key combination to add "pre-ready" piece of code?

Thank you

Comment: and in a few weeks, you'll be back with "I'm sitting on a heap of generated code and need to change it all at once, please help".  your question contains or implies several "worst practices" in programming.

Comment: i know what you mean... what can i use to "automate" the javascript i specified before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using code snippets. [This](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/080710.htm) article explains.